# BSOD MEMORY_MANAGEMENT during install Windows 10 x64

Tags: windows-10, installation, 64-bit

I have a semi-new Asus notebook that hasn't had any problems at all. I decided to swap the default mechanical hard drive with an SSD. The original hard drive that was there had Windows 10 x64 Home edition on it.

The problem is that I have MEMORY_MANAGEMENT BSOD during install of all x64 .iso's that I've tried. The x86 works. The BSOD appears after the Windows screen "loading files". I've checked the RAM with memtest and there aren't any errors.

Comment: remove 1 RAM module before setup

Comment: It's not so easy to remove and I think there is only one module.

Answer (score 0):

I did it cloning the mechanical hard drive to the SSD attaching them to the desktop computer and using this free software
[Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree)

The operation lasted 15 minutes with 500 GB